# Extract dynamic and static columns from dataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I am working on one requirement in which few columns are fixed and few columns are dynamic. i am stuck on the dataframe filter part.

sample dataset:

```
ZR  ER   WS  TG  2/3 5/3  2/6 5/50

q   r    e   q   f    w    q    e
```

NOTE: numeric columns are dynamic(i.e count will change in each file)
I want to filter columns (ZR, ER and all numeric columns).

I tried with .iloc[] but is there any other way that helps me to extract the dataset.

Expected Format:

```
ZR  ER  2/3  5/3  2/6  5/50
q   r   f     w     q   e
```

Comment: In your sample, you have 2 occurrences of 'ER' column but in your output there is only one (the first)

Comment: Do you want a solution for `pandas` or `pyspark`?

Comment: Both are okk for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need test columns by list by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and numeric for test if exist digit use:

```
m = df.columns.isin(['ZR', 'ER']) | df.columns.str.contains('^\d+/\d+$')
df = df.loc[:, m]

print (df)
  ZR ER 2/3 5/3 2/6 5/50
0  q  r   f   w   q    e
```

Comment: you are correct. but I have done some typos in the column name.can you please suggest me for above columns

Comment: @Rishav - answer was edited.

Comment: Working for me. you are superb.

Comment: @jezreal, it is also filtering columns that have alphanumeric values.

Comment: @Rishav - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`:

```
out = df.filter(regex=r'^((ZR|ER)$|\d)')
print(out)

# Output:
  ZR ER 2/3 5/3 2/6 5/50
0  q  r   f   w   q    e
```

A more accuracy expression:

```
out = df.filter(regex=r'^(ZR|ER|\d+/\d+)$')
print(out)

# Output:
  ZR ER 2/3 5/3 2/6 5/50
0  q  r   f   w   q    e
```

Comment: @Rishav. I updated my solution

Comment: @Rishav. The expression could be more precise if you look for an expression like: `number/number`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df[['ZR','ER',23,5,2]]
```

Comment: *"NOTE: numeric columns are dynamic(i.e count will change in each file)"*